# A non-interactive client login to Experience Editor (Sitecore 9.3)

Tags: experience-editor, identity-server, powershell

I am writing a service tool where I need to invoke a web request to Experience Editor page from command line. I need to authorize the request with Sitecore user.

How can I do this?

I found some examples for `Sitecore Commerce`, `Sitecore Command Line Interface`, and `API controllers`.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/configure-a-non-interactive-client-login.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-commerce/bearer-token-authentication.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/use-bearer-tokens-in-client-applications.html

Is there something similar possible with `Sitecore Experience Editor` pages? Or not similar but still possible to use from command line?

Comment: Can you please describe one of the scenarios on what you need from Experience Editor during mentioned request?

Comment: I think that there is a lot of context around Experience Editor operation that will be hard to replicate without actually starting the EE shell. However I can't think of anything that EE does that can't be done using the "normal" APIs so if you can articulate the problem you are trying to solve then we may be able to suggest a more reliable way of solving your problem without having to go through EE to get there.

Comment: The goal is to warm up first request to specific pages in EE mode - if there is a simple way to do it with just a short PS script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login is possible with single POST request

- URL: `/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login`
- Body: `{ "username": "admin", "password": "b", "domain": "sitecore" }`